# Getting Image name given a canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bunch of images I'm using for a chess game in a canvas using wpf, xaml, and C#. I want to use

```
Canvas.SetTop(image, position);
```

to set the position of this image. However I am given the index of child in my canvas and that is it.

```
myCanvas.children[index]
```

I tried

```
Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas.children[index], position);
```

but that did not work. How can I change the position of the image given only the index of the image in the canvas?

Edit: Another option would be to change the position of the canvas child. But I couldn't find anything for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using WPF I expect you don't plan to use a lot of animation, so a better way to do this would be with a Grid:

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Grid x:Name="Board">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

To place something in a cell:

```
void SetPosition(UIElement element, int x, int y)
{
    if (!Board.Children.Contains(element))
        Board.Children.Add(element);
    Grid.SetColumn(element, x);
    Grid.SetRow(element, y);
}
```

You could also use a [UniformGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966258/chessboard-in-wpf).

A completely data-driven answer can be found in [StackOverflow: WPF controls needed to build chess application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563181/1964861)

Answer (score -1):

```
myCanvas.Children[index].SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, position);
```

Comment: Although that line of code could be the solution for the OP, we like answers that actually explain why this is the missing code line and what it does. You can use the 'edit' feature to add more text.